# tag joystick - merge request

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-merge-request

Can we merge [joystick](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joystick) with [controller](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/controller)?

IMO they're basically the same thing and [controller](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/controller) has the larger quantity of questions on it.

Comment: Isn't a joystick a specific controller only available for PC? When someone says controller I think of a controller for an Xbox, PS or Nintendo console (or their PC equivalents) not a joystick/flightstick.

Comment: Many older consoles also had a joystick either as the primary controller (early Atari consoles) or an optional addon (NES, SNES, N64, any Sega...) Analogue sticks are basically a modern interpretation of Joysticks anyway :)

Comment: Ah, ok, I'm a little too young to remember those consoles. In that case merging would be a better idea indeed.

Comment: While it is not that big of a deal joining these tags, "joysticks" are still used for certain kinds of genres. All current consoles still have joysticks in form or fight-sticks, arcade-sticks or arcade-controllers. You will hear all three expressions, depending on whom you ask. They are mainly used for beat em up or fighting games. Check out the Wikipedia entry: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcade_controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been actioned, meta post wasn't updated.